# How to connect to an AFP server from a Windows PC?

Tags: windows, time-capsule, afp

I would like to connect to an AFP server from a windows PC (XP/Vista/7).

The AFP server is a Time Capsule with file sharing over WAN enabled. It seems from my research on internet that it is not possible to setup the Time Capsule to use SMB for the file sharing over WAN.

I know that windows don't support natively AFP. Is there any third party applications which would allow a windows PC to connect to an AFP server. Is installing Bonjour on the PC could help?

I already tried this : https://superuser.com/questions/119923/connect-a-pc-to-mac-os-x-server

Thanks for your help!

Benjamin

---

From : https://superuser.com/questions/196562/how-to-connect-to-an-afp-server-from-a-windows-pc
(I don't know how to migrate my question to here...)

Comment: Try installing bonjour on the PC for the “easy” try.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/7027/1945 :)

Answer (score 3):

Installing Bonjour (aka Zeroconf) doesn't help. Bonjour only announces existing services.

If the server only serves AFP the client needs to understand AFP. The only Windows AFP client I knew was PC MacLan (http://store.ca.com/miramar/miramar.aspx) which seems not to be sold any more. (I still have it installed on an XP box.)

The often cited Microsoft Services for Macintosh was just an AFP server for Windows NT Server.

I think there were efforts at some time to create a FUSE driver as an AFP client on Linux which could in principle be ported to OSX but I haven't heard of that in a long time.

I would love to hear of an AFP client solution though.